# How do you know what $\sum_{n=a}^{\infty}p^n$ converges to if you know $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p^n = \frac{1}{1-p}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

How do you know what $\sum_{n=a}^{\infty}p^n$ if you know  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p^n = \frac{1}{1-p}$ ?

Apparently $\sum_{n=a}^{\infty}p^n$ = $\frac{p^a}{1-p}$, but how can you derive this?

Comment: Write it as $p^a\sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n$

Comment: Observe: $\sum_{n=a}^\infty p^n=p^a\sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n$.

Comment: The difference between the two is $\sum_{n=0}^{a-1}p^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=a}^\infty p^n &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty p^{n+a} \\
&= p^a \sum_{n=0}^\infty p^{n} \\
&= \frac{p^a}{1-p}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Because of the high-school identity:
$$1-p^n=(1-p)(1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1}),$$
rewritten as 
$$\frac1{1-p}=1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1}+\frac{p^n}{1-p}, $$
which shows that
$$\Biggl\lvert\frac1{1-p}-(1+p+p^2+\dots+p^{n-1})\Biggr\rvert=\frac{\lvert p^n\rvert}{\rvert 1-p\rvert},$$
and the latter fraction tends to $0$ if $\lvert p\rvert<1$.